# How to change the ftp server port in ProFTPD

Tags: linux, ftp, webmin, proftpd

I want to change my ProFTPD server port from 21 to 1945. But I didn't find any port mention in the `proftpd.conf` file. When I add port 21 in the conf file and restart the ftp server it shows the following error:

```
Starting proftpd (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
[FAILED]
```

Please help me with finding out how I change my ftp server port. Below is the `proftpd.conf` file:

```
# This is the ProFTPD configuration file
#
# See: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/by-name.html

# Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) Notes:
#
# In Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux, ProFTPD runs confined by SELinux
# in order to mitigate the effects of an attacker taking advantage of an
# unpatched vulnerability and getting control of the ftp server. By default,
# ProFTPD cannot read or write most files on a system nor connect to many
# external network services, but these restrictions can be relaxed by
# setting SELinux booleans as follows:
#
# setsebool -P allow_ftpd_anon_write=1
#   This allows the ftp daemon to write to files and directories labelled
#   with the public_content_rw_t context type; the daemon would only have
#   read access to these files normally. Files to be made available by ftp
#   but not writeable should be labelled public_content_t.
#
# setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access=1
#   This allows the ftp daemon to read and write all files on the system.
#
# setsebool -P allow_ftpd_use_cifs=1
#   This allows the ftp daemon to read and write files on CIFS-mounted
#   filesystems.
#
# setsebool -P allow_ftpd_use_nfs=1
#   This allows the ftp daemon to read and write files on NFS-mounted
#   filesystems.
#
# setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1
#   This allows the ftp daemon to read and write files in users' home
#   directories.
#
# setsebool -P ftpd_connect_all_unreserved=1
#   This setting is only available from Fedora 16/RHEL-7 onwards, and is
#   necessary for active-mode ftp transfers to work reliably with non-Linux
#   clients (see http://bugzilla.redhat.com/782177), which may choose to
#   use port numbers outside the "ephemeral port" range of 32768-61000.
#
# setsebool -P ftpd_connect_db=1
#   This setting allows the ftp daemon to connect to commonly-used database
#   ports over the network, which is necessary if you are using a database
#   back-end for user authentication, etc.
#
# setsebool -P ftpd_is_daemon=1
#   This setting is available only in Fedora releases 4 to 6 and Red Hat
#   Enterprise Linux 5. It should be set if ProFTPD is running in standalone
#   mode, and unset if running in inetd mode.
#
# setsebool -P ftpd_disable_trans=1
#   This setting is available only in Fedora releases 4 to 6 and Red Hat
#   Enterprise Linux 5, and when set it removes the SELinux confinement of the
#   ftp daemon. Needless to say, its use is not recommended.
#
# All of these booleans are unset by default.
#
# See also the "ftpd_selinux" manpage.
#
# Note that the "-P" option to setsebool makes the setting permanent, i.e.
# it will still be in effect after a reboot; without the "-P" option, the
# effect only lasts until the next reboot.
#
# Restrictions imposed by SELinux are on top of those imposed by ordinary
# file ownership and access permissions; in normal operation, the ftp daemon
# will not be able to read and/or write a file unless *all* of the ownership,
# permission and SELinux restrictions allow it.

# Server Config - config used for anything outside a <VirtualHost> or <Global> context
# See: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Vhost.html

# Trace logging, disabled by default for performance reasons
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Tracing.html)
#TraceLog           /var/log/proftpd/trace.log
#Trace              DEFAULT:0

ServerName          "ProFTPD server"
ServerIdent         on "FTP Server ready."
ServerAdmin         root@localhost
DefaultServer           on

# Cause every FTP user except adm to be chrooted into their home directory
DefaultRoot         ~ !adm

# Use pam to authenticate (default) and be authoritative
AuthPAMConfig           proftpd
AuthOrder           mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c
# If you use NIS/YP/LDAP you may need to disable PersistentPasswd
#PersistentPasswd       off

# Don't do reverse DNS lookups (hangs on DNS problems)
UseReverseDNS           off

# Set the user and group that the server runs as
User                nobody
Group               nobody

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 20.  If you need to allow more than 20 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode; in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            20

# Disable sendfile by default since it breaks displaying the download speeds in
# ftptop and ftpwho
UseSendfile         off

# Define the log formats
LogFormat           default "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"
LogFormat           auth    "%v [%P] %h %t \"%r\" %s"

# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) loading
# See README.DSO and howto/DSO.html for more details
#
# General database support (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html)
#   LoadModule mod_sql.c
#
# Support for base-64 or hex encoded MD5 and SHA1 passwords from SQL tables
# (contrib/mod_sql_passwd.html)
#   LoadModule mod_sql_passwd.c
#
# Mysql support (requires proftpd-mysql package)
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html)
#   LoadModule mod_sql_mysql.c
#
# Postgresql support (requires proftpd-postgresql package)
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html)
#   LoadModule mod_sql_postgres.c
#
# Quota support (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab.html)
#   LoadModule mod_quotatab.c
#
# File-specific "driver" for storing quota table information in files
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab_file.html)
#   LoadModule mod_quotatab_file.c
#
# SQL database "driver" for storing quota table information in SQL tables
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab_sql.html)
#   LoadModule mod_quotatab_sql.c
#
# LDAP support (requires proftpd-ldap package)
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_mod_ldap.html)
#   LoadModule mod_ldap.c
#
# LDAP quota support (requires proftpd-ldap package)
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab_ldap.html)
#   LoadModule mod_quotatab_ldap.c
#
# Support for authenticating users using the RADIUS protocol
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_radius.html)
#   LoadModule mod_radius.c
#
# Retrieve quota limit table information from a RADIUS server
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab_radius.html)
#   LoadModule mod_quotatab_radius.c
#
# SITE CPFR and SITE CPTO commands (analogous to RNFR and RNTO), which can be
# used to copy files/directories from one place to another on the server
# without having to transfer the data to the client and back
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_copy.html)
#   LoadModule mod_copy.c
#
# Administrative control actions for the ftpdctl program
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ctrls_admin.html)
LoadModule mod_ctrls_admin.c
#
# Support for MODE Z commands, which allows FTP clients and servers to
# compress data for transfer
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_deflate.html)
#   LoadModule mod_deflate.c
#
# Execute external programs or scripts at various points in the process
# of handling FTP commands
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_exec.html)
#   LoadModule mod_exec.c
#
# Support for POSIX ACLs
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_facl.html)
#   LoadModule mod_facl.c
#
# Support for using the GeoIP library to look up geographical information on
# the connecting client and using that to set access controls for the server
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_geoip.html)
#   LoadModule mod_geoip.c
#
# Allow for version-specific configuration sections of the proftpd config file,
# useful for using the same proftpd config across multiple servers where
# different proftpd versions may be in use
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_ifversion.html)
#   LoadModule mod_ifversion.c
#
# Configure server availability based on system load
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_load.html)
#   LoadModule mod_load.c
#
# Limit downloads to a multiple of upload volume (see README.ratio)
#   LoadModule mod_ratio.c
#
# Rewrite FTP commands sent by clients on-the-fly,
# using regular expression matching and substitution 
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_rewrite.html)
#   LoadModule mod_rewrite.c
#
# Support for the SSH2, SFTP, and SCP protocols, for secure file transfer over
# an SSH2 connection (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_sftp.html)
#   LoadModule mod_sftp.c
#
# Use PAM to provide a 'keyboard-interactive' SSH2 authentication method for
# mod_sftp (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_sftp_pam.html)
#   LoadModule mod_sftp_pam.c
#
# Use SQL (via mod_sql) for looking up authorized SSH2 public keys for user
# and host based authentication
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_sftp_sql.html)
#   LoadModule mod_sftp_sql.c
#
# Provide data transfer rate "shaping" across the entire server
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_shaper.html)
#   LoadModule mod_shaper.c
#
# Support for miscellaneous SITE commands such as SITE MKDIR, SITE SYMLINK,
# and SITE UTIME (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_site_misc.html)
#   LoadModule mod_site_misc.c
#
# Provide an external SSL session cache using shared memory
# (contrib/mod_tls_shmcache.html)
#   LoadModule mod_tls_shmcache.c
#
# Provide a memcached-based implementation of an external SSL session cache
# (contrib/mod_tls_memcache.html)
#   LoadModule mod_tls_memcache.c
#
# Use the /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny files, or other allow/deny
# files, for IP-based access control
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_wrap.html)
#   LoadModule mod_wrap.c
#
# Use the /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny files, or other allow/deny
# files, as well as SQL-based access rules, for IP-based access control
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_wrap2.html)
#   LoadModule mod_wrap2.c
#
# Support module for mod_wrap2 that handles access rules stored in specially
# formatted files on disk
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_wrap2_file.html)
#   LoadModule mod_wrap2_file.c
#
# Support module for mod_wrap2 that handles access rules stored in SQL
# database tables (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_wrap2_sql.html)
#   LoadModule mod_wrap2_sql.c
#
# Implement a virtual chroot capability that does not require root privileges
# (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_vroot.html)
# Using this module rather than the kernel's chroot() system call works
# around issues with PAM and chroot (http://bugzilla.redhat.com/506735)
LoadModule mod_vroot.c
#
# Provide a flexible way of specifying that certain configuration directives
# only apply to certain sessions, based on credentials such as connection
# class, user, or group membership
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ifsession.html)
#   LoadModule mod_ifsession.c

# Allow only user root to load and unload modules, but allow everyone
# to see which modules have been loaded
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_dso.html#ModuleControlsACLs)
ModuleControlsACLs      insmod,rmmod allow user root
ModuleControlsACLs      lsmod allow user *

# Enable basic controls via ftpdctl
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_ctrls.html)
ControlsEngine          on
ControlsACLs            all allow user root
ControlsSocketACL       allow user *
ControlsLog         /var/log/proftpd/controls.log

# Enable admin controls via ftpdctl
# (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ctrls_admin.html)
<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
  AdminControlsEngine       on
  AdminControlsACLs     all allow user root
</IfModule>

# Enable mod_vroot by default for better compatibility with PAM
# (http://bugzilla.redhat.com/506735)
<IfModule mod_vroot.c>
  VRootEngine           on
</IfModule>

# TLS (http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_tls.html)
<IfDefine TLS>
  TLSEngine         on
  TLSRequired           on
  TLSRSACertificateFile     /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem
  TLSRSACertificateKeyFile  /etc/pki/tls/certs/proftpd.pem
  TLSCipherSuite        ALL:!ADH:!DES
  TLSOptions            NoCertRequest
  TLSVerifyClient       off
  #TLSRenegotiate       ctrl 3600 data 512000 required off timeout 300
  TLSLog            /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
  <IfModule mod_tls_shmcache.c>
    TLSSessionCache     shm:/file=/var/run/proftpd/sesscache
  </IfModule>
</IfDefine>

# Dynamic ban lists (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ban.html)
# Enable this with PROFTPD_OPTIONS=-DDYNAMIC_BAN_LISTS in /etc/sysconfig/proftpd
<IfDefine DYNAMIC_BAN_LISTS>
  LoadModule            mod_ban.c
  BanEngine         on
  BanLog            /var/log/proftpd/ban.log
  BanTable          /var/run/proftpd/ban.tab

  # If the same client reaches the MaxLoginAttempts limit 2 times
  # within 10 minutes, automatically add a ban for that client that
  # will expire after one hour.
  BanOnEvent            MaxLoginAttempts 2/00:10:00 01:00:00

  # Inform the user that it's not worth persisting
  BanMessage            "Host %a has been banned"

  # Allow the FTP admin to manually add/remove bans
  BanControlsACLs       all allow user ftpadm
</IfDefine>

# Set networking-specific "Quality of Service" (QoS) bits on the packets used
# by the server (contrib/mod_qos.html)
<IfDefine QOS>
  LoadModule            mod_qos.c
  # RFC791 TOS parameter compatibility
  QoSOptions            dataqos throughput ctrlqos lowdelay
  # For a DSCP environment (may require tweaking)
  #QoSOptions           dataqos CS2 ctrlqos AF41
</IfDefine>

# Global Config - config common to Server Config and all virtual hosts
# See: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Vhost.html
<Global>

  # Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
  # from being group and world writable
  Umask             022


  # Allow users to overwrite files and change permissions
  AllowOverwrite        yes
  <Limit ALL SITE_CHMOD>
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
DefaultRoot ~

</Global>

# A basic anonymous configuration, with an upload directory
# Enable this with PROFTPD_OPTIONS=-DANONYMOUS_FTP in /etc/sysconfig/proftpd
<IfDefine ANONYMOUS_FTP>
  <Anonymous ~ftp>
    User            ftp
    Group           ftp
    AccessGrantMsg      "Anonymous login ok, restrictions apply."

    # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
    UserAlias           anonymous ftp

    # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
    MaxClients          10 "Sorry, max %m users -- try again later"

    # Put the user into /pub right after login
    #DefaultChdir       /pub

    # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, '.message' displayed in
    # each newly chdired directory and tell users to read README* files. 
    DisplayLogin        /welcome.msg
    DisplayChdir        .message
    DisplayReadme       README*

    # Cosmetic option to make all files appear to be owned by user "ftp"
    DirFakeUser         on ftp
    DirFakeGroup        on ftp

    # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
    <Limit WRITE SITE_CHMOD>
      DenyAll
    </Limit>

    # An upload directory that allows storing files but not retrieving
    # or creating directories.
    <Directory uploads/*>
      AllowOverwrite        no
      <Limit READ>
        DenyAll
      </Limit>

      <Limit STOR>
        AllowAll
      </Limit>
    </Directory>

    # Don't write anonymous accesses to the system wtmp file (good idea!)
    WtmpLog         off

    # Logging for the anonymous transfers
    ExtendedLog         /var/log/proftpd/access.log WRITE,READ default
    ExtendedLog         /var/log/proftpd/auth.log AUTH auth

  </Anonymous>
</IfDefine>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.4>
ServerName esdev.wiantech.net
<Anonymous /home/esdev/ftp>
User ftp
Group ftp
UserAlias anonymous ftp
<Limit WRITE>
DenyAll
</Limit>
RequireValidShell off
ExtendedLog /home/esdev/logs/ftp.log
</Anonymous>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 122.176.97.151>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 122.176.97.151>
ServerName "klarify15.wiantech.net"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 122.176.97.151>
ServerName "klarify15.wiantech.net"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Port directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_Port.html):

```
Port <port number>
```

A note that if you set port to `N`, then you must let port `N-1` available too. [RFC959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) defined that source port for active data transfer **must** be `N-1`.

You can use `Port` directive both in server context or virtual server context. Setting `Port 0` disable server.

Comment: as you mention when I add any port number in conf file it shows `Starting proftpd (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.`
[FAILED]

Comment: @user3676417: try run `proftpd -d 10` to see what happen?

Comment: After running this command what need to check ?

Comment: when I add port within <global> </global> then it throws Fatal: Port: directive not allowed in <Global> context on line 354 of '/etc/proftpd.conf'

Comment: @user3676417: `Port` directive only works in server context or virtual server context. Read the manpage carefully.